# Validate table existence from sysmaster query

Tags: sql, informix

I am trying to develop a query over sysmaster to validate if specific table exists on databases

I have done the query over sysmaster:

```
select x0.sid,
       x0.username,
       x0.hostname,
       x1.sqs_dbname,
       dbinfo("UTC_TO_DATETIME",x0.connected) AS conn_dt
  from sysmaster:"informix".syssessions x0,
       sysmaster:"informix".syssqlstat x1,
       sysmaster:"informix".sysnetworkio n
 where (x0.sid = x1.sqs_sessionid)
   and hostname is not NULL
   and trim(hostname) <> ''
   and trim(hostname) <> '-'
   AND sqs_dbname NOT LIKE 'sys%'
   AND sqs_dbname <> '-'
   AND n.sid = x0.sid
```

I would like on the same query validate if one specific table exists over sqs_dbname result.

Comment: Ideally, you should show what you want as output — and how you'd provide the specific table name.  Would that be something like `AND ZZZ.tabname = 'the_chosen_name'` as an extra condition on a specific table or table alias `ZZZ`?

Comment: Which data comes from `sysnetworkio`?  Or does the join mean you don't get to see sessions that don't do network I/O (don't have a session entry in `sysnetworkio`)?

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. I am looking for a table name grlf_lig exists on database to read it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple query joining with sysmaster:systabnames should work.